# Why doesn't my node environment variable get

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I'm trying to build a node module where in some instances I'll pass in a path of a json config file, and sometimes I'll want to set the config file location as an environment variable.

My module which loads it's children looks like this

```
module.exports = (config){
    config_file = config || process.env.CONFIG_PATH;
    return require('./lib/obj_builder.js')(config_file);
}
```

In my spec, I'm loading this module as

```
process.env.CONFIG_PATH = './tests/mock_env_config';
var module_with_config = require('./index.js')('./tests/mock_config');
var module_using_env_var = require('./index.js')();
```

The tests using `module_with_config` pass fine, but the module doesn't pass the environment variable. I'm not sure why.

Comment: since you are requiring the same file twice... that might lead to a caching issue. Try having 2 seperate files - index.js and index_env.js and see if that gives you the results you want.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking this would be easier than two files, but I guess I may as well have the user pass in the env variable or string, rather than look for the env variable if the string isn't present. Thanks